# Transposing rows into columns - An Issue faced.

Tags: mysql

I'm having the following data set (note that my database/schemata  is somewhat complex so it's not feasible to include all the details here)

This is a simplified version of my data which I extracted from my base tables and created a `view`.

```
workout_activity_record_id  attribute_metric_id attribute_metric_value  workout_exercise_set_created_on
234                                17              10                          2012-02-06 00:00:00
234                                18              30                          2012-02-06 00:00:00
234                                17              20                          2012-03-03 00:00:00
234                                18              12.9                        2012-03-03 00:00:00
234                                17              20                          2012-04-02 00:00:00
234                                18              40                          2012-04-02 00:00:00
.
.
. (So on for further workout_activity_record_ids)
```

I need to compute (look up in the data to understand better)

```
Grand Total = (10 * 30) + (20 * 12.9) + (20 * 40)
```

grouped by month.

A basic approach here that would aid in multiplying is transpose the rows into columns. So the above structure would become -

```
workout_activity_record_id     ex17  ex18       workout_exercise_set_created_on     
234                            10     30        2012-02-06 00:00:00
234                            20     12.9      2012-03-03 00:00:00
234                            20     40        2012-04-02 00:00:00
.
.
.
.
.  (And so on for remaining workout_activity_record_ids)
```

For this, I went through several SO posts and after trying out various viable/non-viable (:D) options, I came up with the following query.

```
SELECT
       CASE attribute_metric_id
           WHEN '17' THEN attribute_metric_value END AS 'ex17',
       CASE attribute_metric_id WHEN '18' THEN attribute_metric_value END AS 'ex18', 
       workout_exercise_set_created_on
FROM exercise_attribute
WHERE workout_activity_record_id =234
```

And the actual output I got was

```
workout_activity_record_id  ex17    ex18    workout_exercise_set_created_on 
234                          10      NULL   2012-02-06 00:00:00
234                          NULL    30     2012-02-06 00:00:00
234                          20      NULL   2012-03-03 00:00:00
234                          NULL    12.9   2012-03-03 00:00:00
234                          20      NULL   2012-04-06 00:00:00
234                          NULL    40     2012-04-02 00:00:00
```

Can anyone shed some light over this? I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This computes the grand total for you, grouped by year and month:

```
SELECT YEAR(workout_exercise_set_created_on) AS YEAR,
       MONTH(workout_exercise_set_created_on) AS MONTH,
       sum(SubTotal) AS GrandTotal
FROM
  (SELECT workout_exercise_set_created_on,
          max(CASE WHEN attribute_metric_id = 17 THEN attribute_metric_value END) * max(CASE WHEN attribute_metric_id = 18 THEN attribute_metric_value END) AS SubTotal
   FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY workout_exercise_set_created_on) a
GROUP BY YEAR(workout_exercise_set_created_on),
         MONTH(workout_exercise_set_created_on)
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fe19/12)

**Output**

```
YEAR    MONTH   GRANDTOTAL
2012    2        300
2012    3        258
2012    4        800
```

Comment: Updated with group by Year, Month

Comment: Thanks! This works well enough for me. But, could you please explain a bit more on how you constituted and put together the various parts of this query?

Comment: The subquery calculates subtotals for each date. Then the outer query sums those subtotals for each year/month.

Comment: Note: I just cleaned up (simplified) the query a bit, there was some leftover cruft.

Answer (score 1):

Just add aggregate function :

```
SELECT
   MAX(CASE attribute_metric_id
        WHEN '17' THEN attribute_metric_value 
      END) AS 'ex17',
   MAX(CASE attribute_metric_id 
        WHEN '18' THEN attribute_metric_value 
       END) AS 'ex18', 
   workout_exercise_set_created_on
   FROM exercise_attribute
   WHERE workout_activity_record_id =234
   GROUP BY workout_exercise_set_created_on
```

If you need to show results for different `workout_activity_record_id` you should modify  `group by workout_activity_record_id,workout_exercise_set_created_on`

Comment: Sorry, but I get only one record if I use `MAX`.

Comment: Didn't you forget `group by workout_exercise_set_created_on` ? If `workout_exercise_set_created_on` is in `select` and `group by`, it should return 1 row per each distinct `workout_exercise_set_created_on`... If it's not what you wanted, I probably misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I missed including it in group by... Thank you by the way for replying...